# Inconsistent behaviour when assigning object, missing members

Tags: angular, typescript

I have come across a situation in my Angular application - when assigning object from constant to a property, and passing it later onto a child component, last member of array in the object disappears. This can be verified by logging out the object.

At the moment I am using a work-around of adding empty `{}` to the `.foo` array in my configuration object, and this seems to work, but I would like to use proper configuration without any stop-gaps.

I would also include stackblitz for this, but I was unable to replicate the behaviour. Any guesses as to what could cause this?

EDIT: https://stackblitz.com/edit/inconsistent-assign-angular

See my simplified code below.

```
-------- constants.ts --------
export const CONFIG = {
  foo: [
    {title:"0",...}
    {title:"1",...}
    {title:"2",...}
    {title:"3",...}
    {title:"4",...}
    {title:"5",...}
    {title:"6",...}
    {title:"7",...}
    {title:"8",...}
    {title:"9",...}
    {title:"10",...}
  ]
}
```

```
-------- parent.component.ts --------
import CONFIG from constants.ts

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  configuration = CONFIG

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.configuration.foo) // Prints 10 members
    console.log([...this.configuration.foo]) // Prints all 11 members
  }
}
```

```
-------- parent.component.html --------
<child-component [config]="configuration" /> // Only sees 10 members
```

```
-------- child.component.ts --------
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input("config") configuration: ConfModel

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.configuration.foo) // Also missing last element!!
  }
}
```

[image: Missing member]

Comment: Could you please include a CodeSandbox or Stackblitz anyway just so I can try a few things out?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-examples-injrhb?devToolsHeight=33&file=app/parent/parent.component.ts

Comment: Yes they are same type as other members. If I switch out the order, a different (still last) element would disappear. Interesting that devtools sees length of array printed as 11 in both times, which could hint at something?

Comment: Is there any mutation of values anywhere in the application?

PS (Apologies for accidentally deleting my previous comment)

Comment: No, neither the constant nor the configuration is being mutated elsewhere

Comment: For testing purposes, what happens if you change the constant to a variable or use `let`?

Comment: No change, even assigning the object in component instead of importing is results in last member being omitted.

Comment: I am almost completely out of ideas, and the fact that this isn't reproducable is very strange. Have you tried restarting the dev server & clearing the browser cache?

Comment: That was one of my first steps. This behaviours occurs on our stage environment, not just locally on my device which leads me to believe this is some piece of (un)intended behaviour somewhere deeper, possibly some kind of arcane interaction.

Comment: I don't know if it's an error typing the question, but should be: `import CONFIG from './constants.ts'`. (It's looks like strange not use quotes when you import) and you forgot the `,` after each element in your code.). If in your real application you're getting the constant not using import else using httpClient.get, be sure that the .json file is "reached" -should be in assets folder- and not cached.